# Transplanting raspberries in Nov after first planting them in the previous spring

Tags: raspberries

I live in south central KY. I have raspberry bushes I dug up Nov 5th this year. They were just set out back in the spring this year. Two of them have long canes now. I found 3 berries on them when I dug up. But had not noticed any other berries previously. Should I cut all the canes back to the ground. They are currently setting in pots with root ball and some potting soil on top. Also should I wait and plant after the leaves fall off or go ahead and replant now.

Answer (score 1):

You should have replanted them when you dug them up, if the original site is not where they will be long-term. But if they haven't been left to dry out too much they should be fine if you replant them as soon as possible.

Pruning advice varies for different types of raspberries, and we (and possibly you) don't know what type you have. For all types, any canes **other** than last year's new ones should be pruned off after leaf fall. For some types, pruning off last year's new canes will negatively impact next year's fruiting.

In an established bed, thinning of the canes you're leaving is also needed, (or at least beneficial) but that's unlikely for a new set of plants getting transplanted.